# Can a native visualiser modify the display of an item, based on the parameter name of its collection?

Tags: visual-studio, natvis

In my company, the developers are regularly using `CMapStringToStr` objects, and always the pointers have the same type, for a particular parameter, e.g.

```
m_mapUsers  : every pointer is a CL_USER object
m_mapOthers : every pointer is a CL_OTHER object
```

I already have made a native visualiser for expanding the `CMapStringToPtr` in a reasonable readable way, as you can see in this excerpt:

```
m_mapUsers
  0: ["User1"]     0x12345     void*
  1: ["User2"]     0x23456     void*
  ...
m_mapOthers
  0: ["Other1"]    0x98765     void*
  1: ["Other2"]    0x98764     void*
  ...
```

I'd like to have the `m_mapUsers` and the `m_mapOthers` entries to be recognised, in order to get a result like the following:

```
m_mapUsers
  0: ["User1"]     {user=..., group=..., ...}     CL_USER
  1: ["User2"]     {user=..., group=..., ...}     CL_USER
  ...
m_mapOthers
  0: ["Other1"]    {reason=..., code=...}     CL_OTHER
  1: ["Other2"]    {reason=..., code=...}     CL_OTHER
  ...
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I did this in my project is first to have a generic visualization for my linked list. This is what you already have.

```xml
<Type Name="MyLinkedList">
  <Expand>
    <LinkedListItems>
      <HeadPointer>this</HeadPointer>
      <NextPointer>next</NextPointer>
      <ValueNode>pData</ValueNode>
    </LinkedListItems>
  </Expand>
</Type>
```

Then I went to the classes where I knew how to interpret the `void` pointers, to which type I should cast them. So I created a `Synthetic` value with the same name as the member variable, changed the `HeadPointer` from `this` to the name of the member variable and at last did a type cast for the `ValueNode`.

```xml
<Type Name="MyClass">
  <Expand>
    <Synthetic Name="m_list">
      <Expand>
        <LinkedListItems>
          <HeadPointer>m_list</HeadPointer>
          <NextPointer>next</NextPointer>
          <ValueNode>(TheKnownType*)pData</ValueNode>
        </LinkedListItems>
      </Expand>
    </Synthetic>
  </Expand>
</Type>
```

The disadvantage is that I need to copy the code to multiple places, but it works.

Depending on the types that your pointers point (for example always `CObject`?) to it might also be possible to detect the type in the `MyLinkedList` and depending on the right `Condition` select what to display.